# Unable to load cache item Play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, java-11

I am new to Play framework and I am trying to run a simple Play scala project, I do execute command: ***sbt compile***,and it shows this:

> Version 2.8.18 running Java 19

and then execute command:  ***sbt run***
but the following error shows up:

> ERROR play.api.http.DevHttpErrorHandler
> ! @7pmkokico - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected
> exception[UncheckedExecutionException:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item]
> at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:254)
> ... 25 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item

When executing ***java --version*** command, it shows:

> java 11.0.17 2022-10-18 LTS
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269, mixed mode)

When I execute command: ***sbt --version*** it shows:

> sbt version in this project: 1.7.2
>
> sbt script version: 1.8.0

So, I saw that this error shows up when java version is not higher than 11 , but in my case I cannot see why it is happening?

Comment: Could you clean the stack trace to keep only relevant items? Hard to read.

Comment: I believe Play is not compatible with Java17+ for now. So you should probably downgrade to Java 11. Why is SBT using Java 19?

Comment: It shows like that , I don't know; When I check for Java version it says it is Java 11.0.17 !!!!

Comment: Do you have SBT options maybe? You can force a Java install with `-java-home` argument when running SBT to test.